# Combining multiple assets for a single animation with FlxSprite

Tags: animation, sprite, haxe, haxeflixel

I have a `FlxSprite` variable named `mySpr` and two png files, `one.png` and `two.png`, inside the `assets/` folder of my project.

Each png file include 4 frames and has a size of 200x200px. Can I do something like this?

```
mySpr.loadGraphic("assets/one.png",true,100,100);  
mySpr.loadGraphic("assets/two.png",true,100,100);  
mySpr.animation.add("run", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10, true);
```

Or is there any way to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the function `FlxSprite.stamp()` for "appending" the second image to the side of the first (or any other location), after that is just a matter of adding another animation.

`FlxSprint.stamp` function documentation: https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxSprite.html#stamp

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise using `FlxAtlas` for that. It could look like

```
import flixel.graphics.atlas.FlxAtlas;

...

var atlas = new FlxAtlas("some_unique_atlas_name");
atlas.addNode("assets/one.png");
atlas.addNode("assets/two.png");

mySpr.loadGraphic(atlas.graphic,true,100,100);
mySpr.animation.add("run", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10, true);
```

In addition, you can use `FlxAtlas` to set up animations that are presented in separate assets. You can have a look at [this demo](https://haxeflixel.com/demos/FlxAtlas/) and its source code to find more details